# I want my div to show in desktop after I toogle the div close in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a simple toggle button to hide and show. My coding skills in `Javascript`/`Jquery` are very bad.

In desktop view the description is showing perfectly fine.
(Picture in [Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUg3p.jpg).)
, while in mobile there's a button to toggle hide and show the description.
(Picture in [Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzTqS.jpg).)
.

However, when I toggle hide the description in mobile view it disappear in desktop view when i dragged the browser. Only when I toggle show in mobile, it likely to show on the desktop. How do I make it appear?

Javascript:

```
//Script
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toogle-button").click(function () {
            $(".toggleholder").slideToggle("slow");
            $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-down");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
//html
<div class="toogle-button">Introduction<i class="pull-right fa fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
<div class="toggleholder">
    <div class="desc-holder">
        <p>
            <p><b>Subject:</b></p>
            <span class="side-text">Design</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <p><b>Description:</b></p>
            <span class="side-text">This quiz is to test your knowledge on HTML basic foundation.</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="user-holder">
    <p><b>Assigned By:</b></p>
    <div class="profile-holder">
        <div class="avatar-holder">
            <img src="/include/images/default/avartar_32.png" class="avatar32" />
        </div>
        <div class="username">Admin Asriah Asadi</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css/Less:

```
.toogle-button {
display: none;
margin-top: 15px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #055eac;
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: trigger resize event and check for window/browser width and if it satisfies requered with trigger the show()

Comment: Java is not Javascript. Javascript is Javascript. Jquery goes together with Javascript, not Java

Comment: here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/q4d0wg03/

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks my bad, it's javascript not java. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the event handler `window.resize`, and what do you do on new scale:

```
$(window).resize(function()
 {
   var desktop_mobile_breakpoint = 768; //or whatever else!! it should be you @screen-xs-max...
   //when you drag your window
   if ($(window).width() > desktop_mobile_breakpoint) $('.toggleholder').show(); //desktop: we show it
   else $('.toggleholder').hide(); //mobile: we hide it
});
```